# Error con Sweet Alert 2 Swal.mixin(...).queue is not a function

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

El día de hoy me apareció de pronto un error al usar Sweet Alert 2. El error es el siguiente

> Uncaught TypeError: Swal.mixin(...).queue is not a function

El error me apareció de pronto y sin yo modificar nada por meses, simplemente apareció sin más. Me puse a verificar si todo estaba bien aunque no había movido nada y efectivamente lo único que no funciona es la función que usa "Queue". Pero para mayor seguridad me fui a Sweet Alert en la versión 10 que es la que uso y en los ejemplos tampoco esta funcionando el ejemplo que usa la función "Queue" dando exactamente el mismo error. Que debo hacer? debo esperar que se solucione solo o debo programar una alternativa. ¿Es normal estos errores ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto, me descargue los archivos version 10.16.7 y funciono nuevamente sin el cdn. La nueva actualizacion no tiene la funcion queue.

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.16.7/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.16.7/dist/sweetalert2.min.css